# How can I use dymola to produce FMU with 64bit dll

Tags: dymola, fmi

I need to use [dymola](/questions/tagged/dymola) to produce **fmu-file** with **64-bit-dll**.
The condition is:
I use [bin64-version-dymola](/questions/tagged/bin64-version-dymola), but **fmu-file** is **32-bit-dll**
I searched internet, and I found I should set flag Advanced.CompileWith64=2.
But problem is, I can not find the location for setting Advanced.CompileWith64=2.
**Anyone know where I can set the value of Advanced.CompileWith64?**

Answer (score 2):

You have to input that in the command line on the Simulation tab (ctrl+F2) as you can see in the screenshot below.

I hope this helps,
Marco

[image]

Comment: It works! That's very nice of you! And I am sorry I missed this reply for such a long time. Thank you so much for your advice. Right now it runs well. Wish you have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest Dymola version, e.g. 2014 FD01. Install Visual Studio 2012 that contains VC++ 2012 Express Edition. You will need only the compiler so there is no need for a license. This compiler is capable of generating 64 bit code. In the Simulation Setup/Compiler tab, select Visual Studio 2012/Visual C++ Express Edition (11.0). In the FMI tab select 64-bit binaries.